# Getting assertion error, even when both expected and actual values are same

Tags: java, rest-assured

Need help in below assertion error.
When i make below API call, though both actual and expected are same, i am getting this exception.

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import com.jayway.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;


public class firstRestCall 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        RestAssured.get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/Norway").
        then().
        body("capital",equalTo("Oslo"));
        //body("capital",equalTo("[Oslo]"));  tried this also, but getting the same exception
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path capital doesn't match.
Expected: Oslo
  Actual: [Oslo]

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) etc....
```

Comment: `body("capital",equalTo("Oslo"));` needs to be `body("capital".equalTo("Oslo"));` You have a comma in there instead of a period.

Comment: print the length of both variables,you might find an extra space in one of them

Comment: Or is that line correct?

Comment: Try the assertion again with "[Oslo]" the actual value has the brackets and the expected does not according to the output.

Comment: If i call the webservice in browser, http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/Norway     i am getting below response, [{"name":"Norway","capital":"Oslo","altSpellings":["NO","Norge","Noreg","Kingdom of Norway","Kongeriket Norge","Kongeriket Noreg"],"relevance":"1.5","region":"Europe","subregion":"Northern Europe",etc...]  what is the right way to validate the capital value?

Comment: @Nicholas, when i add ".", inplace of "," it shows compile time error. As in my code i already tried with [Oslo], but still getting the assertion error.

Comment: Is there a line return at the end of the actual value? I notice there is a gap between the the output and the stack trace.

Comment: Can you please help me how can the value of capital into a string variable? Can we capture this into Response and traverse to path and get the required value?

Answer (score 4):

`capital` probably returns multiple values (a list of values) and thus you should use the `hasItem` Hamcrest matcher:

```
RestAssured.get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/Norway").
        then().
        body("capital",hasItem("Oslo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you are extracting is in a list/object so you can't use equalTo on the object itself. Use the hasItem matcher instead.

```
 body("capital",hasItem("Oslo"));
```